# The Foundry Nuke – Get a file path of font

Tags: python, nuke

I need to programatically get the location of all fonts used in a Nuke script. If you open a text node in the GUI you can see the font file path under `Font` however using the following code I only get a tuple of font family, font style. This gets me part of the way there.

Interestingly if I print out the text node itself I am able to see at least the filename of the current font, but this information is not available any way I can figure out.

The documentation for [FreeType_Knob](https://learn.foundry.com/nuke/developers/90/pythonreference/nuke.FreeType_Knob-class.html) does not offer any real solution...

```
for node in nuke.selectedNodes():
    print(node.knob('font').getValue())
```

Answer (score 1):

Allright here's a super messy answer that actually does kind of get the job done. Someone with more regexp knowledge could probably tidy this up:

```
import re

def get_font(node):
    m = re.search(r'(font {{.*}})', str(node))
    line = m.group(0)
    return line.split(":")[2].lstrip().rstrip()

for node in nuke.selectedNodes():
    print(get_font(node))
```

That'll at least get you the font filename. From there you just need to prepend the system font directory, or Nuke font path. Obviously that only covers fonts in those two directories, but it's a start!

Answer (score 0):

> I can't use `Class=Text2` node 'cause when I call it – NUKE unexpectedly quits every time. Thus I tested it with previous `Class=Text`.

I used the mentioned **print** command, inside **for-in** loop, for three selected old Class=`Text` nodes:

```
for node in nuke.selectedNodes():
    print(node.knob("font").value())            # pay attention to syntax
```

in the GUI of NUKE 11.2v4 in macOS 10.14 Mojave and get the following result:

```
# Result: /Library/Fonts/Zapfino.ttf
# Result: /Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf
# Result: /Library/Fonts/Georgia.ttf
```

[image]

If you can't get a fonts' file path – seemingly it's a Windows issue. **Suppose you need to set up environment variables**. Or it's just a problem of a new Class=`Text2` node.

[image]

Comment: That's very different behavior to what I get, if I use `value` instead of `getValue()` I just get `Result: 0.0`. That is pretty unexpected output... but anyway I'm curious why this is working for you on Mac. I am on 11.1v2 so that could definitely be a factor, but I tried version 9 and 10 with the same result. Why would environment variables have to do with this?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tell – I used `Class=Text`, not a `Class=Text2` using `Comp Script Command` (or pressing `X` hotkey). If I call `Class=Text2` – NUKE unexpectedly quits every time. The `Class=Text2` is the only node that doesn't work (show) at all.

Comment: Whoa, sorry you lost me there. What's `Class=Text`?

Comment: `Text` is the previous version of text node, `Text2` is the new one. I'll publish a picture in 5 mins.

Comment: I see. Well I need to be able to run this on existing scripts which are using Text2. Funny that the old class works, guess they lost something there. Feature request time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182537/discussion-between-gigantic-and-spencer).

Comment: You can read `knob info` about new class `Text2` node in `Comp Script Command...` window. For old `Text` node "font" knob = `/Library/Fonts/FONT.ttf`. Read this string for new `Text2` node, maybe this string is different there.

Comment: Select the node and press "`I`" shortcut.

Comment: Sorry, was working on something else and missed your chat. For the node info I get `font Utopia : Regular : UtopiaRegular.pfa : 0`. If I can get at that filename I can just extrapolate the path on disk by finding the local fonts folder (and checking the nuke default fonts folder). I'm going to try parsing the data out of the node info, as soon as I figure out how to get that in python...

Comment: Ok well you did lead me to a hacky solution, see my answer!